# "self" object for UIViewcontroller has @"0 objects" in debug window in xcode

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, self

I segue to a Viewcontroller that immediately has 0 objects for "self" and although I can access "self." objects, I cannot see them in the debug window. Without pasting the code, is there a known reason for this to be happening? Thanks!

to clarify:
 In the debug window under "self", i can usually see my variables and classes and what their values are but for this one, I see none and it says @"0 Objects"

Comment: why not pasting your code? Makes the answer much easier...

Comment: It's difficult to know what are you really asking. Are you running the Debug configuration?

Comment: sorry, I thought I would get email when a reply was posted. In the debug window under self, i can usually see my variables and classes and what their values are but for this one, I see none and it says @"0 Objects"

Comment: I have same issue. When i try to debug something in my UIViewController it's self = 0 key/value pairs instead of some bytes.

Comment: I got this problem too. Hard to find the good key words to search. My bug fixing get stuck by it.

Comment: I had to recreate UIViewController all over again

Answer (score 7):

It seems you did copy&paste some controls from other viewcontroller into the viewcontroller in the storyboard and xCode confused about the controls.
Following steps maybe help you.

1. Restart xCode.
2. Open the storyboard.
3. Select all controls in the viewcontroller and delete them.
4. Undo delete.

Comment: My controller is pure coded, no xib or storyboard. I restarted Xcode and even the Mac. It doesn't work.