# Self shows "0 objects" in debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am an iOS noob.
I am having a problem similar to this:

["self" object for UIViewcontroller has @"0 objects" in debug window in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065074/self-object-for-uiviewcontroller-has-0-objects-in-debug-window-in-xcode)

Re-starting xcode does not solve the problem.

I can see the self object in the view controller after a segue from my main view controller. I have a UITableViewController inside that view controller, with a separate class for delagete/data source for the table. Once i get into this tableviewcontroller code, the self object shows "0 objects" in the debugger. I believe that I am initializing the table view incorrectly to cause this problem somehow, but not quite sure how.

Thanks for the help. My code is below.

```
    @implementation ConnectTableController

    @synthesize perpArray;
    @synthesize nameArray;

    + (ConnectTableController *)connectTableController
    {
        return [[ConnectTableController alloc] init];
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        perpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }

....



@interface ConnectTableController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>  {

    UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray* perpArray;
    NSMutableArray* nameArray;
}


+ (ConnectTableController*) connectTableController;


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray  *perpArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray  *nameArray;

...


// Parent view controller code


    @implementation ConnectVC


    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Set the controller delegate/dataSource for the Table
        connectTableController = [[ConnectTableController alloc] init];
        connectTable.dataSource = connectTableController;
        connectTable.delegate = connectTableController;

        [self addChildViewController:connectTableController];

    }
...


    @interface ConnectVC : UIViewController{


        IBOutlet UIButton *CONNECT;

        ConnectTableController *connectTableController;
        IBOutlet UITableView *connectTable;
    }
```

Comment: could it be count of data source

Comment: Check if you gave data source. If so, debug through NSLog. Even sometimes it gives 0 objects but it gives proper information in NSLog

Comment: I thought that setting the data source on this line in the parent view controller would do the trick:
        connectTable.dataSource = connectTableController;


Is that not enough? So, just NSLog (tableView.datasource) to debug further ?

Comment: After studying my code a bit more, I think that much of my problem stems from the incorrect init of my custom tableviewcontroller class. The init results in an object that looks much the same as the self object i see later on.

Comment: Is there a reason that my init (the connectTableController) call would not be calling the UITableViewController init?

Comment: The debugger data display is famously buggy.  Use `po` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to UITableViewControllers as well, make sure you are accessing the views properly

"Self" for a viewController doesn't contain the views, you have to check "self.view.subViews", "Self.view.subViews" contains the views for the viewController, not just "self" alone.

for example, if Self is a UIViewController then the following will crash your app with the corresponding error:

```
for(UIView * a in self)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", a.description);
}

error: 
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f854176fbf0'
```

It crashes because "self" of uiviewController doesn't contain the views

BUT if you try this, then you will have something to work with:

```
for (UIView *s in self.view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

this will log to console all the views in the UIViewController, thereby allowing you to access the views

Also, it looks like you may be trying to access the views of "connectTableController". To access this controller's views then here's how it works:

connectTableController.view.subViews.

```
UITableViewController * aaa = [UITableViewController new];
aaa.tableView;
aaa.view;
aaa.view.subviews;
```

So, this means you are going to access the following:

```
connectTableController.tableView
connectTableController.view.subViews
```

and then from there, you can do this:

```
connectTableController.tableView.subViews
```

.. that is of course if the subviews you are looking for are subviews of the UITableViewController's tableView

In addition, I think the way you are doing the placement of a UITableViewController is OKAY, but probably not the best choice, only because it gets a little complicated and it's not as easy as adding it as a child like that in order to make this work. You should be using something like this:

```
    tester2 = [UITableViewController new];
    [self addChildViewController:tester2];
    [self.view addSubview:tester2.view];
    [tester2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

then of course you should combine this method when/if you want to remove the child view controller

```
- (void)hideContentController:(UIViewController*) content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

This will hopefully give you a start, so also try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the controller delegate/dataSource for the Table
    connectTableController = [[ConnectTableController alloc] init];
    connectTable.dataSource = connectTableController;
    connectTable.delegate = connectTableController;
    [self addChildViewController:connectTableController];
    [self.view addSubview:connectTableController.view];
    [connectTableController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Also, I don't know that you need to do anything with delegation declaration since the child view controller is basically it's own little world within a world. Try it with and without these lines:

```
   connectTable.dataSource = connectTableController;
   connectTable.delegate = connectTableController;
```

What I mean, is possibly declare these in the UITableViewController instance or make sure you are adding the "connectTable to the the UITableViewController, something like this:

```
   cconnectTableController.tableView = connectTable;
```

or

```
[cconnectTableController setTableView:connectTable];
```

then you can try this

```
connectTable.dataSource = cconnectTableController;
```

etc, etc.

Try this for loop and list the results

```
for (id s in self.view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

Comment: Let me study your solution a little more really quick, one second, check the solution I'm posting again, I'll have more info for you, not necessarily the solution per say but perhaps some stuff that may be causing you issues

Comment: Among other things, this is what was printed from the forloop:

VIEW: <UITableView: 0x150000e00; frame = (0 125; 600 475); 
VIEW: <UIButton: 0x14fd0a8b0; frame = (263 58; 106 30); 
VIEW: <_UILayoutGuide: 0x14fd0abe0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; 
VIEW: <_UILayoutGuide: 0x14fd02ef0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES;

Comment: I believe the TableView is being created just fine, its my tableview controller that I am not instantiating correctly.

Comment: Yep, you could be okay, just check to make sure you are placing the child view controller correctly, then see what happens when you do this the way Apple shows in docs here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html      let me show you in your own code, try this look at answer again in one sec

Comment: Yea, I read that article earlier today. Looks like i should go read it again to get more understanding.

Comment: I dont think that I really need to access the subviews of the uitableviewcontroller. I am just trying to use the tableviewcontroller as the datasource/delegate for the tableView created in its parent view controller (ConnectVC.m). I set the view controller as the child a while back when i was trying to debug my "0 object problem." Of course I am a noob, so i could be wrong on all this.

I think my core problem here is still the creation of the UITableViewController in my custom class (ConnectTableController).

Comment: I'll keep checking for a solution, I know how frustrating this crap is, no worries. Proabably easiest if you can find a solution that doesn't force you to create a custom UITableViewController, but I'm going to keep searching, very good question nonetheless.

Comment: When I look at this line in the debugger:     connectTableController = [[ConnectTableController alloc] init];     connectTableController shows "0 objects"

Comment: Also, I just tried this variation on the same sort of viewController combo you have on an app I'm working on, try this for loop.        
    for (id s in self.view.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@", s);
    }

Comment: Okay, perfect, let me think through this, also, what is the variable "connectTable", what is this? I dont' see it declared anywhere. Nevermind, I see it now

Comment: The suggested for loop results in pretty much the same output as the one i tried earlier.